# Can I ask about stage sound systems here?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a few questions about equipment and know-hows related to the physical construction and maintenance of sound systems that are used in middle/large scale corporate/organization events or concerts. Can I ask them here? Or is this community only for studio work?

Answer (score 3):

We handle live sound reinforcement, but not so much corporate telecom.  So if it is a telepresence suite, it's probably borderline at best.  If it's a live sound reinforcement rig, it's very on topic.